# At first it said its not a function, now its just not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Okay, I'm trying to make a cheesy accent generator to practice with RegEx.  But I have a strange problem that seems unrelated to RegEx.  The submit button doesn't do anything.  At first the function "maccent" was just called "accent" and at that time the console said "accent" was not a function.  With nothing better to go on, I assumed it was because the word "accent" was used so many other times, so I changed the function name to "maccent".  Now, however, nothing happens.  What's the deal?  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Accent Generator</title>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <p>Choose an accent</p>
  <input type = "text">

  <form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="accent" value="German"> German<br>
  <input type="radio" name="accent" value="English"> English<br>
  <input type="radio" name="accent" value="Indian"> Indian
</form>

  <button type="submit" onclick = "maccent()">Submit</button>
  <div id = "accented"></div>


<script>

    var accent = $('input[name="accent"]:checked').val();



  function maccent()
  {
    if (accent == "German")
    {
      germAcc();
    }
  }

    function germAcc()
    {
var sample = $("input").val()


var desire = sample.replace(/[w]/gi, "v")
//not if it's at the end of a word

var desire2 = desire.replace(/th/, "z")
//replace h too, but not with another z.
//wait, what?  It replaces t even if its not followed by h

var desire3 = desire2.replace(/er/, "a")
//this is going to be a hard one
//er is replaced with a but only if its followed by a space or a punctuation 
mark.
console.log(desire3);

}

function indAcc()
{
var sample = $("input").val()


var desire = sample.replace(/[r]/gi, "d")
//not if it's at the end of a word


//this words, but not on each indivual word

console.log(desire);

}

function itAcc()
{

}

function britAcc()
{
  var sample = $("input").val();


var desire = sample.replace(/[a]/gi, "au")

var desire2 = desire.replace(/er/, "a")
//this is going to be a hard one

console.log(desire2);


//not if it's at the end of a word
}




  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, `var accent = $('input[name="accent"]:checked').val();` will assign nothing to `accent` because none of the radio buttons are selected on page load.  You need to move that inside `maccent` so you read the checked radio button value after the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the assignment of the "variable" `accent`.  You are doing it at global scope (the top level), so it gets assigned when the page is first loaded.

If you move that assignment into the function `maccent()` (and move the work "mark" back into the comment it belongs to), your page will work.

Incidentally, the old problem was that you had a function and a variable trying to share the name `accent`.  The variable was "winning".